# show progressbar in a list row

Tags: android, android-listview

In my app I am using upload `Button` and `Progressbar` in each and every list row, and I am able to upload images to server as well, but facing a small issue, whenever I do tap on upload button for a list item, it always show `Progressbar` at the last list item row which is visible... why?

Whereas it has to be show `Progressbar` in a same row, for which i am uploading image...

For example: I have 3 images in a list, namely 03.jpg, 02.jpg and 01.jpg, so whenever I do tap on upload button of 03.jpg or 02.jpg or 01.jpg, everytime i am getting progressbar on 01.jpg row !

and in my list only three records are visible, to view more need to scroll...

```
    ViewHolder holder ;
    View v ;

        /*** Get Images from SDCard ***/
        ImageList = getSD();

        // ListView and imageAdapter
        lstView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        lstView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this)); 
        }

        public static List <String> getSD()
        {
            List <String> it = new ArrayList <String>();
            String string = "/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/SamCam/";
            f = new File (string+ CameraLauncherActivity.folder+ "/");
            files = f.listFiles ();

            /***
             * to show last taken image on top using lastModified
             * to sort data
             * to refresh data after (remove or update)
             */
            Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<Object>()
            {
                public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {

                    if (((File)o1).lastModified() > ((File)o2).lastModified()) {
                        return -1;
                    } else if (((File)o1).lastModified() < ((File)o2).lastModified()) {
                        return +1;
                    } else {
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            });
            // <<<<<<<<< END >>>>>>>>>>>

            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
            {
            file = files[i];
            Log.d("Count",file.getPath());
            it.add (file.getPath());
            }

        return it;  
        }

  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // Avoid unneccessary calls to findViewById() on each row, which is expensive!
            holder = null;

                // If this item is to be synced
                if(flags.get(position)) {
                    startUpload(position);

                // Mark as synced
                flags.put(position, false);
                }
 if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_upload, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);

 holder.uploadProgressBar = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    convertView.setTag(holder);
                } else {

                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }
holder.uploadProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                 ..................................

                    // btnUpload
                    holder.uploadImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Upload
                            startUpload(position);
                        }
                    });
                   return convertView;

                  } 
              }

        //Upload
        public void startUpload(final int position) {      

            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                handler.post(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                v = lstView.getChildAt(position - lstView.getFirstVisiblePosition());

                holder.uploadProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                holder.statusImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.bullet_button);

                    new UploadFileAsync().execute(String.valueOf(position));   
                            }
                        });
                    }
                };
                new Thread(runnable).start();
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using the `holder` variable in your runnable in startUpload, but you're never initializing it so basically you're reusing the last `ViewHolder` instance that was assigned to the `holder` variable.
Try something like this:

```
         public void run() {

            v = lstView.getChildAt(position - lstView.getFirstVisiblePosition());

            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();

            holder.uploadProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            holder.statusImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.bullet_button);

                new UploadFileAsync().execute(String.valueOf(position));   
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
```

Comment: same kind of issue, i am facing here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22832072/show-current-list-row-thumb

Answer (score 0):

Where do you initiate

```
 holder.uploadProgressBar?
```

I think

```
 position
```

is your problem..

you always get the last item progressbar because your

```
 position
```

is always the last item's position.
You need to initiate

```
 uploadProgress
```

inside

```
(if (convertView == null) {}) method
```

and let it be rcycled every

```
 getView
```

iteration..

You can use my code for reference:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Sub_Category sub_category = getItem(position);
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        //create new view
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.hit_me_sub_row,parent,false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.uploadProgressBar = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


if(SOME CONDITION)
                holder.uploadProgressBar .setVisibility(8);
            else if(OTHER CONDITION)
            {
                holder.uploadProgressBar .setVisibility(8);
            }
  return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Please post your whole getView() method

Answer (score 0):

just try to use Tag for button as following.

```
holder.uploadImageButton.setTag(position); //add this line
holder.uploadImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Upload
             startUpload((Integer)holder.uploadImageButton.getTag()); //change this line
                                OR  
             startUpload((Integer)v.getTag()); //change this line
             }
        });
```

Comment: getting: Cannot cast from Object to int

Comment: @Moon user `Integer` instead of int

Comment: not done same result, again i took three images, showing latest on top and old at bottom, clicked on upload for 03.jpg and 02.jpg but getting progressbar on 01.jpg row